# How to send the google spreadsheet with a button in that sheet

Tags: javascript

I have created a piece rate "timecard" by day.  The last tab summarizes and totals the sheet for that employee.  I need to email that tab to two different emails.  I have a script, but it doesn't seem to be working to send an email.  Much less with the attachment of either the last tab or the complete file.

I've looked at several tutorials pages as well as several YouTube videos.  None seem to do what I need it to do.  The button is created.  I just need the code behind it to send the email.

```
function sendEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


 GmailApp.sendEmail('test@example.com', 'Test', 'See below.');
}
```

I would expect to at least get an email sent with a subject of "Test" and "See Below." in the body.  But I'm not even getting an email sent to my email address.

Comment: Try the code in the answer block. It's from the link below: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3 - where the employees data is at
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Test';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```